# Rendering freezes

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

when I try to render my animation (I am using blender render) after a certain frame the animation itself freezes. Even if I just render an image beyond a certain frame it is in the same frozen pose. What can i do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information about your project, show images of your dope sheet and render settings. Please help us understand what kind of animation you are dealing with so we can help you better. Please consider uploading your file so it can be inspected. you can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/